# Android touchlistener at specific canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, ontouchlistener

would like to get some helps from fellows. I am creating a custom analog clock which consists of clock dial, hour hand, minute hand, second hand and alarm hand. The user can rotate the alarm hand to set the alarm. I would like to let user to touch only the alarm hand but not other place to set the alarm. However, current on touch listener method I am using will be detecting touch on the whole canvas which including the clock dial, hour hand and etc. How can I detect user touch at the alarm hand and do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas is not a layout so the view your drawn on the canvas will not be a normal view anymore.
It is no possible to listen the touch event just on the alarm part.All you can do is to calculate whether the pointer you touch down(or up) is just on the alarm hand.

Comment: Ok, noted on that. Would like to ask how can I know the pointer of the alarm hand? Thanks.

Comment: Drawable has a method  getBounds which returns its bounds(a rect object),you can use this rect to calculate.

Comment: Do you mean something like this          Rect outRect = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];

    private boolean inViewBounds(View view, int x, int y){
        view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
        return outRect.contains(x, y);
    }

Comment: No it is the view but drawable(Your alarm hand is a drawable object not a view ). private boolean inDrawableBounds(Drawable drawable,int x,int y){rect = drawable.getBounds();then check if point(x,y) is in the rect }

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have tried it and it indeed can check for the specific drawable.

Comment: However, I just realised one issue which is it only detect the original place where the drawable is being draw even though the drawable has been rotated. In my case, the alarm hand will be rotate follow user finger movement. The drawable initially was set at 12 oclock, at this point, user touch on it then it can detect user is touching on the alarm hand. However, when user rotate the alarm hand to 3 oclock and then lif up finger and touch the alarm hand again, it can detect at this point. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out some solutions already. Thanks alot.